# Avoiding exponential values in loadtxt

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matrix, exponential

I have a `csv` file with headers like:

Given this `test.csv` file:

```
"A","B","C","D","E","F","timestamp"
611.88243,9089.5601,5133.0,864.07514,1715.37476,765.22777,1.291111964948
611.88243,9089.5601,5133.0,864.07514,1715.37476,765.22777,1.291113113366
611.88243,9089.5601,5133.0,864.07514,1715.37476,765.22777,1.291120650486
```

If, I use `load.txt` then I get the array with 3 rows and 7 columns with `exponential` values.

```
r1 = numpy.loadtxt(open("test.csv","rb"),delimiter=",",skiprows=1)
```

I get

```
 [[  6.11882430e+02   9.08956010e+03   5.13300000e+03   8.64075140e+02
     1.71537476e+03   7.65227770e+02   1.29111196e+12]
  [  6.11882430e+02   9.08956010e+03   5.13300000e+03   8.64075140e+02
     1.71537476e+03   7.65227770e+02   1.29111311e+12]
  [  6.11882430e+02   9.08956010e+03   5.13300000e+03   8.64075140e+02
     1.71537476e+03   7.65227770e+02   1.29112065e+12]]
```

To avoid `exponential` I used the following code but still it gives the same exponential values. My code to avoid exponential:

```
 r1 = np.loadtxt(open("test.csv","rb"),delimiter=",", dtype=np.float64, skiprows=1)
```

Is there any way to remove the `exponential` while creating the numpy matrix? I know I can remove the values later with `numpy.savetxt(sys.stdout, r1, '%5.2f')` but I want it while creating the matrix not after creation.

Comment: 611.88243 *is* 6.11882430e+02, given the issues associated with floating point arithmetic).  Don't you want to read in the the values?  Otherwise, what sort of result *are* you looking for?  Also, what do you want to do with the last column of input, which is already in the exponential notation (1.291111964948E12)?

Comment: Why does it matter? Is there any difference other than in how they are displayed?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor See my edit, there won't be any exponential value in csv file.

Comment: @RobWatts Yes, I want my matrix to look simple

Comment: @user2481422 Then it's just an issue of how you print it out - there is nothing wrong with the contents of your matrix. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/pretty-printing-of-numpy-array answers how to do that.

Comment: @user2481422 I see your edit, but I don't see an example of the output that you want.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I believe OP is saying even when there are no exponents in the input he still gets them when he prints out the array.

Comment: I *think* that's the case, too, but I'm not sure.  It really shouldn't be so hard though to copy the output that OP *is* getting, edit it in Notepad, and say, "this is what I'm trying to achieve."  It would remove *a lot* of ambiguity.

Comment: OK, is this *not* answered by the related question in the sidebar, [Pretty-printing of numpy.array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2891790/1281433)?  The asker there said, "If I want to print the numpy.array of floats, it prints several decimals, often in 'scientific' format, which is rather hard to read even for low-dimensional arrays. However, numpy.array apparently has to be printed as a string, i.e., with %s. Is there any solution ready for this purpose?"

Comment: @user2481422: In the last column of the sample data, you've lost the scientific notation `E12`; compare to the data shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143807/load-csv-file-to-numpy-and-access-columns-by-name

Answer (score 2):

I hope the comments on the question make clear that this is purely a formatting question.  Also pointed out in the comments, a nice explanation of some of the formatting options for numpy arrays is given by @unutbu here: [How to pretty-printing a numpy.array without scientific notation and with given precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/pretty-printing-of-numpy-array)

An option not shown in that answer is the use of the `formatter` argument to [`np.set_printoptions`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html).  The argument was added to `set_printoptions` in numpy version 1.7.0.  With the `formatter` argument, you can control how numpy prints the elements of arrays.  Here's an example of using that argument to control the format of floating point numbers.

Here's how `a` is printed with the default settings:

```
In [30]: a
Out[30]: 
array([[  6.11882430e+02,   9.08956010e+03,   5.13300000e+03,
          8.64075140e+02,   1.71537476e+03,   7.65227770e+02,
          1.29111196e+12],
       [  6.11882430e+02,   9.08956010e+03,   5.13300000e+03,
          8.64075140e+02,   1.71537476e+03,   7.65227770e+02,
          1.29111311e+12],
       [  6.11882430e+02,   9.08956010e+03,   5.13300000e+03,
          8.64075140e+02,   1.71537476e+03,   7.65227770e+02,
          1.29112065e+12]])
```

Now override the default, and tell numpy to convert floating point values to strings using the format `"%.5f"`.  This format will not use scientific notation, and it will always show five digits after the decimal point.

```
In [31]: np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': lambda x: "%.5f" % (x,)})

In [32]: a
Out[32]: 
array([[611.88243, 9089.56010, 5133.00000, 864.07514, 1715.37476,
        765.22777, 1291111964948.00000],
       [611.88243, 9089.56010, 5133.00000, 864.07514, 1715.37476,
        765.22777, 1291113113366.00000],
       [611.88243, 9089.56010, 5133.00000, 864.07514, 1715.37476,
        765.22777, 1291120650486.00000]])
```

You can add a call to `rstrip` to remove the trailing zeros:

```
In [53]: np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': lambda x: ("%.5f" % (x,)).rstrip('0')})

In [54]: a
Out[54]: 
array([[611.88243, 9089.5601, 5133., 864.07514, 1715.37476, 765.22777,
        1291111964948.],
       [611.88243, 9089.5601, 5133., 864.07514, 1715.37476, 765.22777,
        1291113113366.],
       [611.88243, 9089.5601, 5133., 864.07514, 1715.37476, 765.22777,
        1291120650486.]])
```

Note that in the above, I entered the name in `ipython`, and it echoed back its value.  When used this way, the `repr`-representation of the object is printed.  You'll get the `str`-representation if you explicitly print it:

```
In [55]: print(a)
[[611.88243 9089.5601 5133. 864.07514 1715.37476 765.22777 1291111964948.]
 [611.88243 9089.5601 5133. 864.07514 1715.37476 765.22777 1291113113366.]
 [611.88243 9089.5601 5133. 864.07514 1715.37476 765.22777 1291120650486.]]
```

Comment: Your answer gives this error `TypeError: set_printoptions() got an unexpected keyword argument 'formatter'`.

Comment: @user2481422:  The `formatter` argument was added in numpy 1.7.0 (https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/release/1.7.0-notes.rst#custom-formatter-for-printing-arrays).  What version are you using?