# Import CSV file into numpy as data table resulting in incorrect shape

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I'm trying to use numpy to read in a CSV file as a data table, but having problems.

This is my CSV file, in full:

```
week,count,is_successful,percent,percent_tablet,percent_desktop
1,2005,0,23,32,45
1,3805,1,18,22,55
2,1872,0,35,22,43
2,2990,1,22,21,57
3,2005,0,24,24,48
3,3805,1,27,21,52
```

Here's my numpy code:

```
data = np.genfromtxt("data.csv", delimiter=',', names=True)
print data.shape
```

This gives me `(6,)` - it sees rows but no columns. Why isn't it importing it as a table?

Comment: What does `import pprint; pprint.pprint(data)` show?

Comment: your example has 6 data rows and 6 columns, try adding a row to be sure of what you're seeing...

Comment: If you're not yet wedded to the use of `numpy`, I'd look at [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org): `pd.read_csv("data.csv")` will give you something more like what you're expecting.

Comment: This question is close to being a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143807/load-csv-file-to-numpy-and-access-columns-by-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have named columns, the array created by `genfromtxt` is a one-dimensional [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html).  Access columns using the column names as keys, e.g. `data['week']`.

You can get a two-dimensional view of the data with the `view` method: `table = data.view(np.float64).reshape(len(data), -1)`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html):

> The main way to control how the sequences of strings we have read from
>   the file are converted to other types is to set the dtype argument.
>   Acceptable values for this argument are:
>
> - a single type, such as dtype=float. The output will be 2D with the    given dtype, unless a name has been associated with each column with
>     the use of the names argument (see below). Note that dtype=float is
>     the default for genfromtxt.
> - a sequence of types, such as dtype=(int, float, float).
> - a comma-separated string, such as dtype="i4,f8,|S3".
> - a dictionary with two keys 'names' and 'formats'.
> - a sequence of tuples (name, type), such as dtype=[('A', int), ('B',    float)].
> - an existing numpy.dtype object.
> - the special value None. In that case, the type of the columns will be    determined from the data itself (see below).
>
> In all the cases but the first one, the output will be a 1D array with a structured dtype. This dtype has as many fields as items in the sequence. The field names are defined with the names keyword.

Essentially, if the data is heterogeneous or unspecified, you get an array of dtypes. Only if it's homogeneous do you get a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `skiprows` and leave `names` to its default `False` value.  That would bypass assembling data into structures.

```
data = np.genfromtxt("data.csv", delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
print data.shape
```